# In Lua, do each "object" HAVE to have their own copy of their methods?

Tags: class, oop, lua, prototypal-inheritance

I have a very simple class here:

```
Point = {}
function Point:new(x,y)
   local self = {}
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
   --------------------
   function self.set(x,y)
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
   end
   function self.get()
       return {self.x,self.y}
   end
   --------------------
   return self
end
```

Every instance has all methods in it.
It's a huge waste of memory isn't it?
How do I store an instance's data but only a single copy of their methods?

Comment: Have you seen [Classes](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.1.html)?

Comment: In Lua 5.3, multiple evaluations of a function definition are no longer guaranteed to create distinct function values. This goes against your assumption that there are copies of methods. (The example could be rewritten to explicitly reuse methods across instances, too.) But, yes, without `__index` there has to be a field in every instance for each method.

Comment: The change mentioned above was made in Lua 5.2 (2011).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is metatables. By setting the __index field you can easily "reroute" nil values to the Point table itself. So by storing the methods in Point, you aren't taking up so much memory!

```
Point = {}
function Point.set(self, x,y)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
end
function Point.get(self)
    return {self.x,self.y}
end

function Point.new(self, x,y)
   local point = setmetatable({},{__index = Point})
       point.x = x
       point.y = y
   return point
end

print(table.unpack(Point:new(1,2):get()))
```